# How to hold nft price until all nft are sold?

Tags: pallet, substrate-node

We have created `nft-marketplace` in substrate, 1 collection has `100 NFT`. We only need to send all the amount of nft only after all nft are sold and until we wan't to hold the amount somewhere. How to implement this scenario?

Comment: you implemented this using pallet development or using smart contracts?

Comment: we implemented using pallet @ImmanuelJohn

Answer (score 1):

You could derive a unique account from the NFT collection which receives the funds. When the last NFT of this collection is sold you transfer the funds from the derived account to the NFT collection creator (and remove the derived account).

Comment: can you please tell me how to derive unique account from the NFT collection?

Comment: Something like so: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e526f80a91f75a3811059d4ee19b0f190005c5a2/frame/utility/src/lib.rs#L503-L510